# Can't Ping EC2 instances under same security group

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-security-group

I am unable to publicly ping between two EC2 instances in different subnets only when the security group has entries for ICMP ping that is being sourced from the security group itself as seen below:

[image]

Both of my EC2 instances have this security group attached to them. Outbound rules are left at the default which is allow all outbound traffic. If I change the source to '0.0.0.0/0' then I am able to ping between them, however I want to lock this down to only allow this behavior within this particular security group.

Here are images of the applied security group from my two EC2 instances:

[image]

[image]

I had thought that this policy would allow anything within the security group inbound (since all out is allowed) to receive requests and replies. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: I think it should work when you use private IP addresses for pinging over public ones.

Comment: Also for pinging just `Echo Request` should be enough.

Comment: @Marcin Yes you are correct after verifying.

Comment: Cool. I will make answer then if you don't mind.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the comments the solution was to use **private** IP addresses instead of the public ones.